# Ignored spring batch Tasklets in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-batch-tasklet

spring butch configuration file:

```
@Configuration
public class TransitionConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    System.out.println(">> This is step 1");
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                }).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step2() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step2")
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    System.out.println(">> This is step 2");
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                }).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job jobSimpleNext() {
        System.out.println("starting job");
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("jobNext")
                .start(step1())
                .next(step2())
                .build();
    }
}
```

in case i've started it:

```
2019-06-09 23:32:02.052  INFO 19976 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-06-09 23:32:02.190  INFO 19976 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
starting job
2019-06-09 23:32:02.495  INFO 19976 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: MYSQL
2019-06-09 23:32:02.601  INFO 19976 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils (file:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-core/5.2.0.M2/9a84d456ad8d5151da06fc8a85540da9cc95d734/spring-core-5.2.0.M2.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2019-06-09 23:32:02.705  INFO 19976 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2019-06-09 23:32:02.738  INFO 19976 --- [  restartedMain] o.v.s.b.l.s.t.TransitionsApplication     : Started TransitionsApplication in 2.12 seconds (JVM running for 2.588)
2019-06-09 23:32:02.740  INFO 19976 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner   : Running default command line with: []
2019-06-09 23:32:02.891  INFO 19976 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=transitionJobNext]] launched with the following parameters: [{}]
2019-06-09 23:32:02.931  INFO 19976 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Step already complete or not restartable, so no action to execute: StepExecution: id=19, version=3, name=step1, status=COMPLETED, exitStatus=COMPLETED, readCount=0, filterCount=0, writeCount=0 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=1, rollbackCount=0, exitDescription=
2019-06-09 23:32:02.945  INFO 19976 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Step already complete or not restartable, so no action to execute: StepExecution: id=20, version=3, name=step2, status=COMPLETED, exitStatus=COMPLETED, readCount=0, filterCount=0, writeCount=0 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=1, rollbackCount=0, exitDescription=
2019-06-09 23:32:02.954  INFO 19976 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=transitionJobNext]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
2019-06-09 23:32:02.963  INFO 19976 --- [       Thread-7] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2019-06-09 23:32:02.974  INFO 19976 --- [       Thread-7] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Checking logs we can detect that everything is completed.

### BUT

`Tasklet`s was not executed. I really confused because of this.
Checking DB I've detected that job status is `COMPLETED` but `exit_code` is `NOOP`.

I've detected also, that using `.allowStartIfComplete(true)` for `step` triggers `tasklet` execution. But that like a hack which can be used for the step only single time in the same job scope (it doesn't work for case double execution step in the same job). For example:

```
    @Bean
    public Step step2() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step2")
                .allowStartIfComplete(true)
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    System.out.println(">> This is step 2");
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                }).build();
    }
```

***In case I start project in terminal - it works correctly.***

### My env:

- OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.29+3-CA (build 11.0.2+7-LTS)
- Gradle 5.4.1
- Idea community (just installed latest version)
- OS ubuntu 18.04
- command to start application from idea is:

```
/home/sergii/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/java -javaagent:/home/sergii/IDE/idea-IC-191.7479.19/lib/idea_rt.jar=33229:/home/sergii/IDE/idea-IC-191.7479.19/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/sergii/Development/projects/my/spring/spring-batch-learning/out/production/classes:/home/sergii/Development/projects/my/spring/spring-batch-learning/out/production/resources:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/2.2.0.M3/f7d3810d75b6fb01b7aa1d8df9e21b3bea8c2dbc/spring-boot-starter-actuator-2.2.0.M3.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-devtools/2.2.0.M3/853cb206490a2946646d4bac02446b8dc564be30/spring-boot-devtools-2.2.0.M3.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-batch/2.2.0.M3/fe0bb4352d0c49d9b088db13c6a89fd9619bf2dc/spring-boot-starter-batch-2.2.0.M3.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-mail/2.2.0.M3/ffc975519f3c14e7577d0407845240caa3fc10f9/spring-boot-starter-mail-2.2.0.M3.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/2.2.0.M3/fbd92e6461e5e37186c360f0080af27719780811/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.2.0.M3.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter/2.2.0.M3/d858f3131933381d6661c0f08b6bd9669f581123/spring-boot-starter-2.2.0.M3.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/2.2.0.M3/3a6536cc550e7e555be62d16720c285b40c3c95a/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.2.0.M3.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.16/6088b7a25188ab4b3ab865422a8ec77ade29236/mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.batch/spring-batch-core/4.2.0.M2/60b52cb2d85ead44ecf7b0bf47dfeb6e672316b6/spring-batch-core-4.2.0.M2.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.micrometer/micrometer-core/1.1.4/96eabfe2343a4a4676d215b2122cbbc4d4b6af9b/micrometer-core-1.1.4.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-context-support/5.2.0.M2/fa3009cdce6b4155da8833bb003577991cd71908/spring-context-support-5.2.0.M2.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.sun.mail/jakarta.mail/1.6.3/787e007e377223bba85a33599d3da416c135f99b/jakarta.mail-1.6.3.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.2.0.M3/3d990f3a7716875013570a1ddd9c79a5dc556390/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.0.M3.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-actuator/2.2.0.M3/e08a8914653e13395ddaf23fde41570d919b8109/spring-boot-actuator-2.2.0.M3.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/2.2.0.M3/fc0b424da418b242c3d953bd6bbf06f03bfb1925/spring-boot-2.2.0.M3.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/2.2.0.M3/ae4dc76f8f14327ca3a792584f666d484f21b5/spring-boot-starter-logging-2.2.0.M3.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/jakarta.annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/1.3.4/a858ec3f0ebd2b8d855c1ddded2cde9b381b0517/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.4.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-context/5.2.0.M2/c85d8095c7765d8d38b9b6a357aa347b617bab79/spring-context-5.2.0.M2.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/5.2.0.M2/ea5a41f2b01a2a5f88426e3a509f53479e2b6c41/spring-jdbc-5.2.0.M2.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.batch/spring-batch-infrastructure/4.2.0.M2/b522e7c7f1c5ebb575136f149b0408462d391e22/spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.0.M2.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-aop/5.2.0.M2/8deb00a5c5e18b6c594877afe4e82b8b8d64ccb/spring-aop-5.2.0.M2.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-tx/5.2.0.M2/7042f477e471796be677f71ec63575ac7c47a749/spring-tx-5.2.0.M2.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-beans/5.2.0.M2/c4aa2bb803602ebc26a7ee47628f6af106e1bf55/spring-beans-5.2.0.M2.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.retry/spring-retry/1.2.4.RELEASE/e5a1e629b2743dc7bbe4a8d07ebe9ff6c3b816ce/spring-retry-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-expression/5.2.0.M2/cdf6909ed2decf704486ca85395e97177fd7535b/spring-expression-5.2.0.M2.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-core/5.2.0.M2/9a84d456ad8d5151da06fc8a85540da9cc95d734/spring-core-5.2.0.M2.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.8/11283f21cc480aa86c4df7a0a3243ec508372ed2/jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hdrhistogram/HdrHistogram/2.1.9/e4631ce165eb400edecfa32e03d3f1be53dee754/HdrHistogram-2.1.9.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.latencyutils/LatencyUtils/2.0.3/769c0b82cb2421c8256300e907298a9410a2a3d3/LatencyUtils-2.0.3.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.zaxxer/HikariCP/3.3.1/bb447db60818ecfdbb1b99e7bd096ba7a252d91a/HikariCP-3.3.1.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.24/13a9c0d6776483c3876e3ff9384f9bb55b17001b/snakeyaml-1.24.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.9.8/28ad1bced632ba338e51c825a652f6e11a8e6eac/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.8.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.batch/javax.batch-api/1.0/65392d027a6eb369fd9fcd1b75cae150e25ac03c/javax.batch-api-1.0.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.codehaus.jettison/jettison/1.2/765a6181653f4b05c18c7a9e8f5c1f8269bf9b2/jettison-1.2.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.sun.activation/jakarta.activation/1.2.1/8013606426a73d8ba6b568370877251e91a38b89/jakarta.activation-1.2.1.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/7c4f3c474fb2c041d8028740440937705ebb473a/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/2.11.2/6d37bf7b046c0ce2669f26b99365a2cfa45c4c18/log4j-to-slf4j-2.11.2.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.26/8031352b2bb0a49e67818bf04c027aa92e645d5c/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.26.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.9.0/7c10d545325e3a6e72e06381afe469fd40eb701/jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-jcl/5.2.0.M2/988d5bac4a51ed2675626378ee79f8447eda2002/spring-jcl-5.2.0.M2.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.9.8/f5a654e4675769c716e5b387830d19b501ca191/jackson-core-2.9.8.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.26/77100a62c2e6f04b53977b9f541044d7d722693d/slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/1.2.3/864344400c3d4d92dfeb0a305dc87d953677c03c/logback-core-1.2.3.jar:/home/sergii/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api/2.11.2/f5e9a2ffca496057d6891a3de65128efc636e26e/log4j-api-2.11.2.jar org.vl.spring.batch.learning.springbatchlearning.transition.TransitionsApplication
```

### Question

I guess the issues with idea, because of it works in terminal. Is any ways to analyze and detect a reason for my case and fix it, how?

### P.S.

I've done next unsuccessful tries to fix it:

- reinstal idea;
- recreate project from prepared sources and from spring start;
- restart idea invalidating caches
  -

Comment: are you using multiple profiles ?

Comment: no, single profile

Comment: Check that this code is actually executed, eg by placing the breakpoint or logging.

Comment: As i wrote in details it is for terminal only. But it isn't executed in intellij idea neither `system.out` nor breakpoints or logging. I tried hope everything before publishing question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seem was no intellij idea issues...
I've tried to remove my configured `datasource` trying experiment with default one using embedded db. It works correctly. Next thing that I've done, I used my first `datasource` configuration but with different step names. That works. Checking DB I've detected that every executed step has `COMPLETED` status.

Continue investigation... 
Every my step has `COMPLETED` status in the DB. By default spring batch doesn't allow execute completed steps.

To make `COMPLETED` steps handled one more time we can:

- update `COMPLETED` status in DB with `STOPPED` or `FAILED` - **that is really hack**
- use in step builder function `.allowStartIfComplete(true)` - **the feature of spring batch**.